# Synchronization of data from local database to live server using SQL Server

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, ado.net

I have one server installed locally and other is company,s live server. I have an application installed on local machine, so whenever I run my application data on both SQL Server instances (local and live) should sync to keep same database on both servers how this can be done live database in cloud server with public ip and local databases are in my local system. I would be happy if anyone could provide sample format for this using asp.net C#

Comment: What ever you're smoking, I want it.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use [SQL Server Replication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/sql-server-replication?view=sql-server-2017).